# PHP: Как получить массив различий при сравнении двух ассоциированных массивов и получить только значения, которые встречаются только в одном из них?

Tags: php

Извините за беспокойство. У меня такая проблема, есть два массива:

1)

```
 $array1 = array(
'фрукт' => array('яблоко', 'груша', 'апельсин', 'лимон'),
'овощь' => array('кабачок', 'капуста', 'патисон'),
'ягода' => array('малина', 'земляника'),
);
```

2. 

```
$array2 = array(
'фрукт' => array('груша', 'слива', 'апельсин'),
'овощ' => array('кабачок', 'капуста', 'картошка'),
);
```

Нужно сравнить второй с первым и получить новый массив, в котором есть только значения и ключи, которые не встречаются в $array2. В $array1 могут попасться новые ключи, которых вовсе нет в $array2, в идентичном ключе, который присутствует в обоих массивах может найтись новое значение. Оно есть в $array1, но еще не добавилось в $array2. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сравнить $array1 с  $array2 и получить массив с разницей: если ключ в $array2 есть, то только новое значение, которое можно найти в $array1, если ключа в $array2 нет, то добавить в результирующий массив и новый ключ и все его значения.

**Что пробовал?**

Пробовал $array_diff(), $array_diff_assoc(). Второй должен бы сработать, но вернул пустой массив, хотя разница в двух массивах была. Попробовал написать свою функцию с двумя foreach

```
foreach ($array1 as $fl) {
     foreach ($array2 as $subfl) {

}
}
```

Тоже ничего не вышло...

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Output какой должен быть у представленного примера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант для двух аргументов(По сути не отличается от варианта Tunker):

```php7
<?php
// Your code here!
$array1 = [
    'фрукт' => ['яблоко', 'груша', 'апельсин', 'лимон'],
    'овощ' => ['кабачок', 'капуста', 'патисон'],
    'ягода' => ['малина', 'земляника'],
    'зелень' => ['кинза','базилик'],
];

$array2 = [
    'фрукт' => ['груша', 'слива', 'апельсин'],
    'овощ' => ['кабачок', 'капуста', 'картошка'],
];


function diff(array $array1, array $array2): array {
    $result = $array1;
    foreach ($result as $key => $values){
        if( array_key_exists($key, $array2)){
            $result[$key] = array_diff($values, $array2[$key]);
            if($result[$key] === []){
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(diff($array1, $array2));

?>
```

Вариант для неопределённого количества аргументов.

```php7
<?php
    $array1 = [
        'фрукт' => ['яблоко', 'груша', 'апельсин', 'лимон'],
        'овощ' => ['кабачок', 'капуста', 'патисон'],
        'ягода' => ['малина', 'земляника'],
        'зелень' => ['кинза','базилик'],
    ];
    
    $array2 = [
        'фрукт' => ['груша', 'слива', 'апельсин'],
    ];
    
    $array3 = [
        'овощ' => ['кабачок', 'капуста', 'картошка'],
        'зелень' => ['кинза','базилик'],
    ];
    
    function diff(...$arrays): array {
        if($arrays === []){
            return [];
        }
        $len = count($arrays);
        $result = $arrays[0];
        for($i = 1; $i < $len; $i++){
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                if(array_key_exists($key, $arrays[$i])){
                    $result[$key] = array_diff($value, $arrays[$i][$key]);
                    if($result[$key] === []){
                        unset($result[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
    
    print_r(diff($array1, $array2, $array3));
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
'фрукт' => array('яблоко', 'груша', 'апельсин', 'лимон'),
'овощь' => array('кабачок', 'капуста', 'патисон'),
'ягода' => array('малина', 'земляника'),
);

$array2 = array(
'фрукт' => array('груша', 'слива', 'апельсин'),
'овощь' => array('кабачок', 'капуста', 'картошка'),
);

function array_compare($array1, $array2)
{
    $diff = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $values)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array2))
            $diff[$key] = $values;
        else
        {
            $diff[$key] = array();
            foreach ($values as $value)
                if (!in_array($value, $array2[$key]))
                    array_push($diff[$key], $value);
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}

$dif = array_compare($array1, $array2);
print_r($dif);
```

На выходе получаем элементы которые есть в 1 массиве, но нет во втором

```
Array
(
    [фрукт] => Array
        (
            [0] => яблоко
            [1] => лимон
        )

    [овощь] => Array
        (
            [0] => патисон
        )

    [ягода] => Array
        (
            [0] => малина
            [1] => земляника
        )

)
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, эта штука работает дольше, чем то, что я описал...

Comment: @lith-al я понимаю, у меня вложенный цикл, но не уверен, что сортировка двух массивов и потом сравнение будет быстрее. Можете привести рабочий пример, тогда можно сравнить скорость.

Comment: А зачем пример-то?) Сортировка -- это O(n*log(n)), а у тут вроде O(n*sqrt(n))